# What would happen if we used a spray on a spaceship?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A spray works like a [Reaction Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_control_system), but would it change the velocity of a spaceship we are on even sligtly? Consider an astronaut that uses a deodorant.

Comment: Has the spacecraft expelled any reaction mass?

Comment: How fast is the spaceship moving? In vector terms, you would eventually achieve a (very ) wide turn, given even a small initial  deflection. That's how some asteroid earth collisions may be avoided, if we get sufficient warning. How this would work out at relativistic speeds though, I can't be 100 percent  sure.

Comment: Internatioanal Space Station is a good aproximation
And the spacecraft did nothing against that spray.

Comment: Expelling mass outside (as control system) has an effect, but inside (as a deodorant) do not (why?).

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the astronaut using the deodorant spray is floating freely in the middle of a compartment.

When he activates the spray, the particles of spray move off in one direction, while the astronaut moves off in the other direction.  Since total momentum is conserved, the velocities of the two entities are in inverse proportion to their masses.  So far, the hull of the ISS is unaffected.

However, two further interactions take place.

Consider first the eventual collision of the recoiling astronaut with the wall of his compartment.  if he hits and sticks, then he has transferred most of his momentum to the frame of the ISS, and the ISS will take up a very, very slow recoil. If he bounces off, he will have transferred *more* momentum to the ISS, but he is now in line to hit the other wall of the ISS, removing some of the ISS's extra momentum, and so on, and so on....

The sprayed particles are more of a problem. Some will (one hopes) stick to the astronaut, and any change in the momentum of the particles and astronaut with respect to those particles being sprayed will cancel out.

Other particles will collide with the opposite wall and stick, and the same process will occur with them as with the astronaut.

Very small spray particles will collide with air molecules and be slowed down.  But these same air molecules will gain velocity in that direction, and collide with the wall eventually. So the spray will eventually transfer its momentum to the ISS as well.

Short story:  when all the motion of astronauts, spray particles and air molecules sorts itself out, no momentum has left the ISS, and its velocity is unchanged. The only possible effect is that the slightly larger forces on the opposite walls will be enough to split the ISS apart.

The details of a hard sneeze are left to your imagination...